# query string on page with no query string option

Tags: query-string

I have a page that doesn't use query strings.
ex. https://testsite.com/defalut.aspx

Our network admin runs a vulnerability scan and says there is an issue with some of the pages.
This is the URL that is breaking it
ex. https://testsite.com/default.aspx?<<<<<<<<<<foo"bar'314>>>>>=1

I know the software he is using adds this query string during the test, but how can I exclude query strings like this on pages where there is no check for a query string?

I thought since there is no check for a query string that the page would load without issue.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 C#, IIS 10.

Report results

```
Using the GET HTTP method, Nessus found that :
+ The following resources may be vulnerable to SQL injection (on        
parameters names) :

> /default.aspx?'%2Bconvert(int,convert(varchar%2C0x7b5
d))%2B'=1
-------- request --------
GET /default.aspx?'%2Bconvert(int,convert(varchar%2C0x7b5d))%2B'=1
HTTP/1.1
Host: testsite.com
Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.9,*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en
Connection: Close
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=f1lv3mbn4qodbzm44wjhlhizxswe3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
Trident/4.0)
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png,   
*/*
------------------------
-------- output --------
<html>
<head>
<title>ORA-12520: TNS:listener could not find available handler for requ
 ested type of server</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<style>
------------------------
```

Thank you

Comment: Commented but changing comment to answer though you will probably get better answers from others :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more information I think.

The penetration test will flag an issue if the response from a request like the one shown has some detail that suggests a possible vulnerability eg some of the query string appearing in the response might suggest XSS etc.

The scan results will provide more information about why that request reveals a potential vulnerability -  ask your network admin for access to the full report, as that will enable you to determine if there is a potential problem that you need to address or if it is a false positive. My guess is that the framework you are using is reflecting the query string in links on the page but that's a real guess.

Expanding a bit in light of our chat and question update. For vulnerabilities such as injection attacks and XSS the main defences are blacklisting input, whitelisting input and neutralising untrusted data.

Blacklisting is generally a last resort - whatever patterns you can block there are likely to be ways around it.

Whitelisting, if possible, can be effective for preventing malicious data coming in via your application but may not be enough on its own. If any of the content on your site comes from persisted data, is there any other way of malicious data getting in? Are there any other applications that can update the data? Who has access to execute sql directly? Social engineering is a real threat where people with access can be tricked into doing dangerous things.

Neutralising untrusted data means different things depending on the threat. For sql injection, untrusted input is neutralised by using prepared statements - never concatenate user input into a statement.

For XSS neutralising generally means escaping any data that may be used maliciously. This would usually be when outputting data on the page rather than at time of input, because the appropriate form of escaping depends whereabouts in the page content the data is included - is it in a block of text, or in an href attribute or within a script on the page.

In your case, as you never expect request parameters you can probably take quite a simple approach. Either whitelist (by rejecting any request with a query) or neutralise input (by stripping off any query). If you have a webserver like Apache httpd in front of your application server, I think either could be done with MOD_REWRITE, else I think asp.net has similar request rewrite capabilities.

Whether to whitelist or neutralise just affects the user experience and probably doesn't matter - realistically it is unlikely that an actual user would be sitting at a screen sending potentially malicious requests. Most public sites are inundated with automated attack attempts similar to your penetration test.

It sounds like some of your page content does depend on data from a database so although the above would resolve your pen test warnings, it is worth considering escaping output to be really safe. I assume that asp.net has some built in functions to support that.

I'm also a bit concerned if error messages are getting dumped into the page title as appears to be the case - detailed error information is a vulnerability in its own right as it can give attackers a lot of useful information about your site implementation, and useful feedback on the effect of different attack attempts.

Best place to read more is the [OWASP website](https://owasp.org/)

Comment: Thank you Chris, I'm unable to post anything from the report.  I work under very strict rules.  What would I need to look for to see if it is a false positive?  I think the "<" or ">" causes it to return a XSS, correct?

Comment: Hiya, totally appreciate that pen test results can't be shared here, but if you have the report, does the report give you the html response from that request? And does it say exactly what problem it has identified (or thinks it has identified)

Comment: False positive would be down to your knowledge of the application - ie if you see whatever the report flagged up, but you can say with absolute certainty that this could not be a problem then it's a false positive. However query parameters reflected back in html source could be genuinely problematic (eg a link with a query string containing executable JavaScript that is sent by email). Usually risks like that are managed by both escaping output and validating input - in your case if you don't expect query parameters can you configure it to return 400 response if any are received?

Comment: Hi Chris, I was able to get the first part of the report and change any info that could be identifiable.  If the page page doesn't use query strings how can it cause this type of message?  Thank you

Comment: But back to your first comment, I suspect that if the response includes those < and > unescaped then the pen testing tool would flag a potential XSS risk

Comment: Since I know there should be no query string can I pull the url without the query string and load it?  or should I redirect the user to a warning page?  I want to make sure I take the correct approach.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: Wow, saw the update, that is a real issue - you are getting an ORA error in the page title. It needs a bit of investigation, although you are not expecting query parameters I guess that asp.net does some processing before it gets to your code that is vulnerable to that particular attack. The title may be giving away some very helpful information to an attacker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226897/discussion-between-jerry-warra-and-chris).